# filewriter not writing to file even though no error

Tags: java, netbeans

I have some code that I have been using for a long time to write to a .txt file in the csv format, but for some reason it will no longer actually produce a new file. The file writing function is executing normally and flushing and closing without any error, but then no file is created. Below is a simplified example that is still not working.

`
import java.io.FileWriter;
public class test {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "SO example";
         FileWriter writer=null;
        try{
            writer = new FileWriter(filename);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            try{
            writer.append("some text\n");
            System.out.println("after append");
             } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            try{
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
            System.out.println("finished writing file "+ filename);
            }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("exception 3: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

}
`

This should create a file called "SO example, but when I search for that file on my computer, it doesn't show up. I am using Netbeans btw. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Did you look in the Netbeans project folder?

Comment: @immibis, yes, I searched the whole computer and also specifically looked in the netbeans project folder.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and make sure you are managing your resources properly.  The file will be created within the execution context of the program, so I'd start by looking in there.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(new File(filename).exists())` to the end of the method and maybe ``System.out.println(new File(filename).getAbsolutePath())`` so you can see where the file is been written to...

Comment: add `if(!new File(filename).exists())new File(filename).createFile();` in the beginning to ensure the file is actually created

Comment: @Paul Don't do that. `new FileWriter()` already does that. Doing it again is just a waste of time and space. Worse, because `new FileWriter()` just has to delete it and recreate it (or rather the operating system has to do so). Try using a more sensible filename that you can find more reliably.

Comment: Thank you all for the help -- I know this is going to sound crazy but I didn't change anything and just tried it again and now it works. Strangely, when I searched in that directory this time several of the files I tried to create before but couldn't find were suddenly there. And yes, I am 100% positive it was the same directory. I would say it was that my file explorer just had a glitch but I turned my computer off and on and still found the error. But anyways thank you for the useful functions!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code on my computer and everything seems to work fine. I am running Ubuntu and eclipse, however.

I would recommend checking where NetBeans stores your project directory and check in there. Don't forget to refresh the directory if you are looking for the file from the directory hierarchy manager within NetBeans.